# Change configuration on azure website when using GIT to deploy

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

How do I configure my website to use either test or release configuration when I'm deploying using GIT? I can configure the branch I want to use, but the the build configuration.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of when looking in to deploying to Azure from Github.  Shouldn't the Azure Portal have a drop down (or textbox) to select the build configuration to use when compiling?  Seems like a huge omission to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a custom deployment script, as described in this [post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1).

Once you do that, you have a lot more control over how your app is built. In this case, you can just tweak the msbuild command like it runs to use whatever configuration you want, much like you'd do if you ran msbuild on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I found a link to Kudu from one of your blogposts. Right not I have a git branch used for test deployment. And added settings to the website on azure to handle test parameters. And so far it works ok. I'll have a look and try the other approach, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can now add an app setting for this on the configure page instead of going to the trouble of a custom deploy script.

SCM_BUILD_ARGS -p:Configuration=[CONFIGURATION_VALUE]

e.g.

> [KEY] SCM_BUILD_ARGS
>
> [VALUE]
>   -p:Configuration=QA

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings